# Format footer values in ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angular-ui-grid

How do I format the aggregate value for a column in ui-grid?

With my numbers I get something horrible like

```
total: 6370.046074130321
```

when I would like

```
total: $6370.05
```

I tried both:

```
footerCellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" >{{COL_FIELD | currency}}</div>',
```

and

```
footerCellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" >{{grid.getCellValue(row, col) | currency}}</div>',
```

but none of them work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The templates you had tried will work for the normal cell values but your are trying to get the template work on a aggregate value.

To get the aggregate value for the column inside a template you can use  `{{col.getAggregationValue()}}` and add your format options.

Since you want to have two decimals this would be more like `{{col.getAggregationValue() | number:2 }}`

Also remember the template will be different if you have column filters enabled on the grid.

Answer (score 6):

if you need the after decimal point to show two values then use custom template functionality in grid options

```
       {
            field: 'ORGINAL_FUNC_AMOUNT',
            displayName: 'CR A/C',
            aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum,
            footerCellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" >Total: {{col.getAggregationValue() | number:2 }}</div>'
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$templateCache.put('ui-grid/uiGridFooterCell',
"<div class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents\" col-index=\"renderIndex\"><div>{{ col.getAggregationText() + ( col.getAggregationValue() CUSTOM_FILTERS ) }}</div></div>"  );
```

CUSTOM_FILTERS = footerCellFilter property
grid.colDef[0].footerCellFilter = 'number:2'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [number](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) filter to choose the amount of decimal you need.

```
{{'$' + valueToFormat | number:2}}
```

Otherwise, you can use a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) function to filter the text/value yourself.

In your module you add:

```
.filter('customFilterFunction', function() {
return function(input) {
    var out = "";
    out = '$' + parseFloat(input).toFixed(2);
    return out;
  };
})
```

In your HTML you add:

```
{{valueToFormat | customFilterFunction}}
```

Comment: it's that `valueToFormat` that I need. As you can see from my original question I have already done that ( | currency) but I am using `COL_FIELD` which doesn't appear to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I use the ui-grid - v4.9.1 (2020-10-26), and I have the same formatting problem...  `col.getAggregationValue()` returns the rigth aggregate value, but `col.getAggregationText()` doesn't return the label...

After some debugging sessions, i retrieve the label in `col.treeAggregation.label`, and also my template is:

```
colDef.footerCellTemplate = '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents cellAlignRight" >{{col.treeAggregation.label}} {{  ( col.getAggregationValue()  | number: 2) }}</div>'
```